# How can I sign a SOAP message (body and a header element) with a SAML assertion token?

Tags: wcf, saml, ws-security, sts-securitytokenservice, ws-trust

The situation is like this:

1. I have a security token from a STS under the form of a [`GenericXmlSecurityToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.genericxmlsecuritytoken(v=vs.110).aspx) (I also have the SAML Assertion element for it).
2. I need to use this security token to call a 3rd party service which needs some extra stuff in the request besides what [`WS2007FederationHttpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.ws2007federationhttpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) can do.
3. The actual SOAP request, besides the SAML assertion element in the SOAP security header, also has to contain signature element (from namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#`) that signs a timestamp element and the body element with the SAML assertion.
4. `WS2007FederationHttpBinding`, as well as a lot of custom bindings variations are unable to include a key reference element in the signature with value type `http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID` (so, the SAML assertion).
5. The most I have been able to get out of them (via `ProtectTokens` = true) is a signed SAML assertion element, but not more.

Basically, what I need to get in the request is this:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security>
    <saml:Assertion=""  AssertionID = "ID_56eecf2a-a143-4ec9-ab85-479d8602122f">
      ...
    </saml:Assertion>
    <WSU:Timestamp>
      ...
    </WSU:Timestamp>
    <ds:Signature>
      <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="#rsa-sha1"/>

        <!--Body signature-->
        <ds:Reference URI="#id">
          <ds:Transforms>
            < ds: Transform  Algorithm = "xml-exc-c14n #" />
          </ds:Transforms>
          <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="#sha1"/>
          <ds:DigestValue >
            di3JiPJM90D3P62ChO1d4Sy12 + 4 =
          </ds:DigestValue DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>

        <!--Timestamp element signature-->
        <ds:Reference  URI = "#Timestamp" >
          <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform  Algorithm = "xml-exc-c14n #" />
          </ds:Transforms>
          <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="#sha1"/>
          < ds:DigestValue>C+GkwwH5RuXocsD0iphwUvmQpj0=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue>kq+FG6qqdx...==</ds:SignatureValue>

      <!--Key reference, pointing back to the SAML assertion element-->
      <!--This is the actual problem. Didn't manage to add this at all.-->
      <ds:KeyInfo>
        <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0 #SAMLAssertionID">
            ID_56eecf2a-a143-4ec9-ab85-479d8602122f</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id">
  ...
</soapenv:Body>
```

I am, however, at a loss as to how I could configure the `WS2007FederationHttpBinding` (or a custom binding) to add the signature.

What I am working with now:

```
/**
 * 
 * Federation binding stuff
 * 
 */
var federationBinding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
federationBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
federationBinding.Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.AsymmetricKey;
federationBinding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
federationBinding.Security.Message.IssuedTokenType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID";
federationBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256;

/**
 * 
 * Custom binding, the one actually used by the channel
 * 
 */
var binding = new CustomBinding(federationBinding.CreateBindingElements());
binding.Elements.Remove(binding.Elements.FirstOrDefault(i => i is TextMessageEncodingBindingElement));
var messageSecurity = (TransportSecurityBindingElement)binding.Elements.FirstOrDefault(i => i is TransportSecurityBindingElement);

//Remove it, I add another one later
binding.Elements.Remove(messageSecurity);

//Security element configuration
var secBinding = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement()
{
    MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10,
    ProtectTokens = true,
    SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax,
    IncludeTimestamp = true,
    EnableUnsecuredResponse = true,
    DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256
};

secBinding.InitiatorTokenParameters = new IssuedSecurityTokenParameters(
        "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID");
secBinding.RecipientTokenParameters = new IssuedSecurityTokenParameters(
        "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID");

secBinding.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;
```

Besides this, I have also tried using a `TransportSecurityBindingElement`, with the same results: I can get the token in the request, but not the signature.

Any ideas/hints about this are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I ended up implementing the client in Java, with JAX-WS. This worked smoothly, as the JAX-WS API maps well (sometimes 1:1 even) to the WS-Security SOAP elements (wsse:Security).

Basically, I implemented a custom `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>` which calls the STS and then builds the `wsse:Security` element using the SAML token and also signs the timestamp and body of the outgoing request with the token.

Not going to mark this as an answer, since it's really not. Just an alternative. Also got the Tumbleweed badge for this question (hooray).